# Error when signing visual studioextension whit "vsixsigntool"

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am signing an visual studio extension (VSIX) with the following command.

```
vsixsigntool.exe sign /f CodeSigningCertificate.pfx /p MyPassword /fd sha256 MyVSIXProject.vsix
```

The result of the command is successful, but when i add the extension to the VS i get the following message. "Invalid Signature"...Any idea?

[image]

Where the output.
[image]

Comment: See http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2018/01/29/code-signing-a-vsix-package-targeting-multiple-visual-studio-versions/

Comment: @SergeyVlasov i already read this, and the error still happening. See the output image.

Comment: Problem solved. I left the tip here to others. The problem was in the root certificate. The root certificate entity was not registered by default on my machine. I changed the entity of my certificate to "Digicer" and everything is work fine.